# Cheerio guidance: how to combine multiple 'td' classes

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping, cheerio

for example, I want to join **name** and **rank** into one object.

I am parsing through a table to combine the name and rank of a player on a tennis website.

**name.js:**

```
const axios = require('axios');
const cheerio = require('cheerio');

const url = 'https://www.example.com';

axios.get(url).then( (response) => {
  const $ = cheerio.load(response.data);
  const player = [];
  $('.player-cell').each( (i, td)  => {
    player.push( {
        name: $(td).text().trim(),
    });
  });
  return(player);
})
.then ( (player) => {
  console.log(player);
})
```

**rank.js:**

```
const axios = require('axios');
const cheerio = require('cheerio');

const url = 'https://www.example.com';

axios.get(url).then( (response) => {
  const $ = cheerio.load(response.data);
  const player = [];
  $('.rank-cell').each( (i, td) => {
    player.push( {
      ranking: $(td).text().trim(),
    });
  });
  return([player]);
})
.then ( (player) => {
  console.log(player);
});
```

**output (goal):**

{ name: 'x', ranking: 'x' },

.

.

n

Comment: Use request and async/await for god sake. There needs to start being a standard way of doing this stuff and this is definitely not it.

Comment: is this a guide to put me on a better track? https://www.thepolyglotdeveloper.com/2018/05/scraping-paginated-lists-nodejs-cheerio-async-await-recursion/

Comment: @pguardiario - forgot to tag you in my above question

Comment: This is missing a [mcve] here. What does the HTML we're dealing with look like?